# How to move file/files from one folder to another in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I am new to Scala.

I've Googled a lot on how to move files in Scala, but have only found how to move files in Java. I tried to move files using Java `import Java.io.File`, using both:

```
Files.move("FileA", "FileB", StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
Files.move("DirA", "DirB", StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
```

but it didn't work. My code looks like this:

```
Files.move("/public", "/public/images", StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
```

I want to move files from `public` to `public/images`.

Comment: You guess it didn't work, or it did not work? Maybe you should try to give the full system path, yeah? Also, it seems difficult to move a directory into a sub directory of itself, so you'll probably need to loop over the files in the public directory and move them to an images directory

Comment: "i guess it didn't work". Don't make us guess. In what way did it not work?

Answer (score 8):

From my understanding of your question,
 you are trying to pass `String` variables instead of `java.nio.Path` variables to the `Files.move()`.
 The below way works:

```
import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.{Files, Path, StandardCopyOption}

val d1 = new File("/abcd").toPath
val d2 = new File("/efgh").toPath

Files.move(d1, d2, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE)
```

However I see one more issue in your code.
Both `StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING` and `StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE` should work but, you can't move a parent directory directly into it's child directory.

```
$ mv public/ public/images
mv: cannot move ‘public/’ to a subdirectory of itself, ‘public/images’
```

Instead you might want to move `public` -> `tmp` -> `public/images`

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below Scala code from my Github : https://github.com/saghircse/SelfStudyNote/blob/master/Scala/MoveRenameFiles.scala

You need to specify your source and target folder in main function:

```
    val src_path = "<SOURCE FOLDER>" // Give your source directory
    val tgt_path = "<TARGET FOLDER>" // Give your target directory
```

It also rename files. If you do not want to rename files, then update as below:

```
val FileList=getListOfFiles(src_path)
FileList.foreach{f => 
  val src_file = f.toString()

  //val tgt_file = tgt_path + "/" + getFileNameWithTS(f.getName) // If you want to rename files in target
  val tgt_file = tgt_path + "/" + f.getName // If you do not want to rename files in target

  copyRenameFile(src_file,tgt_file)
  //moveRenameFile(src_file,tgt_file) - Try this if you want to delete source file
  println("File Copied : " + tgt_file)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[os-lib](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib) makes it easy to copy files from one directory to another:

```scala
os.list(os.pwd/"public").map(os.move.into(_, os.pwd/"pub2"))
```

The java.io and java.nio libraries are generally difficult to work with (although not that ugly for this particular operation).  It's best to rely on os-lib for filesystem operations.

`os.move.into` takes two arguments: the file that's being moved and the destination directory.

This code is flexible and easily modifiable.  You could easily update it to only move files with a certain file extension.

See [here](https://mungingdata.com/scala/filesystem-paths-move-copy-list-delete-folders/) for more info on how to use os-lib.